# Host Binding Not Working on Lazy Loading

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I have been using @HostBinding for adding classes it was working fine earlier but after implementing Lazy Loading i.e upon  loading components lazily these classes are not modifying

```
import { HostBinding, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
     selector: 'body',
     template: `
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>   
     `
 })
 export class AppComponent {
     @HostBinding('class.login') page: boolean = false;
     @HostBinding('class.nav-sm') isFixed: boolean = true;
     @HostBinding('class.dashboard') isDashboard: boolean = false;
 }
```

Using them in my landing page is directly in constructor getting AppComponent and modifying the classes

Using:

```
 export class LandingComponent {
     constructor(private _rootComponent: AppComponent) {

         this._rootComponent.page = false;
     }
 }
```

It is not working after Laziy Loading, Any idea??

Comment: How are you modifying the classes? Can you reproduce in a Plunker? I don't see why this shouldn't work with lazy loading.

Comment: Updated code on How I'm using

Comment: Do you provide `AppComponent` somewhere? Where and how?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a service and injected in module and building the css object(Output variable , event emitter) as required and emitting it

Subscribing to that event where ever required and setting the host binding.

**Shared Service:**

```
@Output() HostBindingCSS: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();


getCss() {
        return this.HostBindingCSS;
    }

    setCSS(_page: boolean = false, _isFixed: boolean = true, _isDashboard: boolean = false) {
        debugger;
        var obj = { page: _page, isFixed: _isFixed, isDasboard: _isDashboard };

        this.HostBindingCSS.emit(obj);
    }
```

**App Component** Code:

```
export class AppComponent {
    @HostBinding('class.login') page: boolean = false;
    @HostBinding('class.nav-sm') isFixed: boolean = true;
    @HostBinding('class.dashboard') isDashboard: boolean = false;

    constructor(private _emsContextService: EMSContextService) {

        this._emsContextService.getCss().subscribe(res => {
            debugger;
            this.page = res.page;
            this.isFixed = res.isFixed;
            this.isDashboard = res.isDasboard;
        });
    }
}
```

In my pages where ever required I'm using the service and calling the setCSS method.

Answer (score -1):

When loading module as lazy loading that module will be child of some other module and `Host` of that module will be only it's parent. for more referance you can go through https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8451/files
and the solution to specific problem is using service shared by `BaseModule` and lazy loaded module or `Events`

Comment: So You mean , shall I create Host Binding in a shared Service and use it , instead of doing in AppComponent?